# block whatsapp web file transfer but not chating

Tags: whatsapp

I work in an organisation where we need to block WhatsApp web file transfers. Meaning chatting will work but downloading and uploading files
are blocked.

We're using Palo Alto firewalls. I've tried anything on it but nothing seemed to have worked.

Is there any way to do this considering that WA is using E2EE?

Comment: "I've tried anything on it" -- like what?

Comment: Have you looked this up? I googled "whatsapp block attachments" and got all the info provided in the duplicate that is linked above.

Comment: Just filter out the packets who are greater than the average size of text messages.

Comment: @defalt the link above explains that there is a certain domain to block

Comment: iv'e tried url filtering, 
file blocking and ssl decryption...

Comment: You need to explain what you have done. You've provided zero details. Did you block the subdomain mentioned in the linked question? Have you used the built-in policies on the PA to block files? We can't help if we're blind...

Comment: yes i did block all the subdomains..
likewise for the built in PA and custom file blocking policies...